# Error Response from daemon: Docker Container [id] is not running

Tags: docker, docker-container

Error Response from daemon: Docker Container [id] is not running.
Hi Team,
I want to run my docker container from the docker reload script but getting the following error:-

```
Error response from daemon: Container b660899a0--- is not running
```

Please help as soon as possible. I'm stuck since 2-4 days

Comment: By default, docker container will exit immediately if you do not have any task running on the container

Answer (score 0):

By default, the docker container will exit immediately if you do not have any task running on the container.

To keep the container running in the background, try to run it with the `--detach` (or `-d`) argument.

```
docker pull my_image
docker run -t -d --name my_app my_image
```

Comment: To bring up the docker container, using the following command:- docker run -itd -p 7191:8181 -p 5151:5005 --net mynet --ip ${IP} --hostname=my-cluster-1 --name=my-cluster-1.. Then I'm facing the issue of not running the container

Comment: Is it necessary to use atomix to bring up the docker container for ONOS cluster